# The meaning of factor as a verb

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **factor** in the following sentence?

> Some also count built-in inflation as a third cause. This **factors**
> people’s expectations of future inflation. When prices rise, labor
> expects an increase in wages to keep up. But higher wages raises the
> cost of production, which raises prices of goods and services again.
> When this cause-and-effect continues, it becomes a wage-price spiral.

Source of the sentence: https://www.thebalance.com/what-is-inflation-how-it-s-measured-and-managed-3306170

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's a mistake.  Normally, one would say they "factor in" -- that is, include its influence.

Comment: Yeah, they meant to write "factor in." Either that, or it's a really weird use of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it should be "factors in", as to influence.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeeing with the above:

To ‘factor in’ means to understand the implications of something, and take it into account when deciding how to proceed.